# sed replace entire string after match

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Hi I'm trying to sed replace the entire string after a match.

my scenario will be inside my file I have the below values:

```
"XX|TESTFILE|MATCH" "CHANGEME"

"XX|TESTFILE|MATCH1" "CHANGEME1"
```

I need to replace the string after the text ***MATCH" "*** so my expected output will be

```
"XX|TESTFILE|MATCH" "THIS IS CHANGED"

"XX|TESTFILE|MATCH1" "CHANGEME1"
```

Hope it is clear and someone will help.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show an extract from you file and what you expect after the sed execution?

Comment: That is my expected output after sed execution. when the string MATCH" (including the quote) is found, it will be replaced with MATCH" "THIS IS CHANGED" hope this is clear

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
sed -ri '/MATCH\"/ {s/(^\"XX.* \")(.*)(\"$)/\1THIS IS THE CHANGE\3/}'
```

Using sed with -r flag for regular expressions, search for entries with MATCH followed by a double quote and then when encountered, split the line into three section. Print the first section followed by "THIS IS THE CHANGE" and then the third section.